# Can white holes undergo hawking radiations like black hole?

Tags: hawking-radiation, white-holes

Could white holes undergo reverse hawking radiation? This is because of quantum mechanical uncertainty. So for example a pair of particles one a positive and one a negative energy particle. The negative energy escapes the white hole. So could white holes also reverse hawking radiate and get mass through this process. Am I right or is there some unknown physics that would prohibit it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on what you mean by "radiation." A white hole is the time-reverse of a black hole. If you take Hawking's original calculation and time-reverse the whole thing, you get a white hole that *absorbs* radiation from the vacuum. That's just as interesting as a black hole emitting radiation, because a white hole isn't supposed to be able to *absorb* anything in classical general relativity, just like a black hole isn't supposed to be able to emit anything.

If you were asking whether a white hole would *emit* Hawking radiation, then the answer would be less interesting: even in classical general relativity, white holes emit everything. It's the time-reverse of a black hole: you can't *escape* from a black hole (classically), and you can't *stay inside* a white hole (classically).

> could white holes also reverse hawking radiate and **get mass** through this process?

The answer is presumably yes, but there's a catch. Hawking's calculation considers quantum fields in a background spacetime, which means the spacetime doesn't react to the quantum fields. That's just an approximation, of course, and in reality we expect that the spacetime will react, resulting in the loss of mass from a black hole. To implement that in a self-consistent theory requires some kind of quantum gravity theory, and I expect that the existence of white holes in quantum gravity would be exceedingly unlikely, for statistical reasons.

Comment: Naive question. Wouldn't time reversing the Hawking process be like time reversing the breaking of an egg? It's a thermodynamic process so I'm not sure if time reversing makes sense?

Comment: Ha, interesting. I didn't think of it this way but it certainly seems related for if we wouldn't neglect the back-reaction, it'd be an exact calculation and thus, presumably (hopefully? xD) fully reversible. Edit: Or maybe not, I'm confused now. Because the thermodynamic nature comes from taking the partial trace over all the degrees of freedom falling into the black hole (correct me if I'm wrong). So even if we took the gravitational back reaction on spacetime into account, to an outside observer, the process would still look thermodynamic.

Comment: @DvijD.C.  The time-reverse doesn't require switching "inside" and "outside". We would still take the partial trace over the "inside", where the singularity is. In QFT, observables are tied to regions of spacetime, not to particles (or propagating modes), and the partial trace is just an instruction to ignore the observables in a given region. In this case, that region is the "inside", where the singularity is. Time-reversal doesn't change that. Does that address your comment, or did I misunderstand what you meant?

Comment: @DvijD.C.  If that's not what you meant, then maybe this: the time-reverse of a conventional blackbody still looks thermal but with ingoing radiation instead of outgoing. Is that what you meant by still looking thermodynamic?

Comment: Sadly your answer is incorrect this time. A white hole is a time reversal of a black hole only, but not of the entire universe. This reversal is meaningful only on the inside where the metric is dynamic and depends on the direction of time. On the outside the metric is static and is exactly the same for both. So no physical experiment outside can distinguish the two. The external gravitational field of a white hole is the same as of a black hole. For this reason the Hawking radiation, if it exists at all, would be be generated by a white hole exactly the same way as by a black hole.

Comment: Furthermore, both are two sides of a vacuum solution, so a white hole radiates nothing. Even if you perturb the solunion by sending a particle to a vacuum black hole, in your external coordinates, it will get within the Planck length of the horizon in seconds and then never cross the horizon. Now reverse time and perturb the vacuum white hole by sending a particle from inside to cross to outside. In your coordinates, the amount of time it needs to move the Planck length away from the horizon is infinite. And since the universe is not infinitely old, a white hole radiates absolutely nothing.

Comment: "*a white hole isn't supposed to be able to absorb anything in classical general relativity, just like a black hole isn't supposed to be able to emit anything.*" - A black hole isn't supposed to emit anything from inside, but the Hawking radiation is generated outside the horizon. A black hole also isn't supposed to absorb anything to the inside ever in coordinates of any external observer. Similarly, a white hole isn't supposed to absorb anything to the inside, but it attracts matter to the horizon exactly the same way as ablack hole. You never "see" anything crossing the horizon of either.

Comment: "*The answer is presumably yes*" (Re: a white hole gaining mass by emitting the Hawking radiation) - Of course not. This would violate energy conservation, which is obeyed in the Schwarzschild spacetime. A white hole will lose mass the same way as a black hole. A particle falling to either a white hole or black hole will increase its mass. A particle flying away will reduce the mass or either.